# How can i execute FT.CREATE using IDatabase.Execute

Tags: c#, .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using `StackExchange.Redis` with `NRediSearch` in `.Net core` application.

I have a .Net `DataTable` and have created hash keys from the data within this DataTable using using `IDatabase.HashSetAsync` method and they look like below -

```
products:1
products:2
...
products:n
```

Now i need to create index on the data so i can perform search operations. This index should be applied to all the DataColumns within the DataTable.

I see we have IDatabase.Execute command to do this but it wont work.

```
ConnectionMultiplexer s_redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("...:6379,password=...");
var db = s_redis.GetDatabase();
var indexCommand = $"FT.CREATE idx:{key} ON HASH PREFIX 1 {key}: SCHEMA"; //here key = products
foreach(DataColumn dataColumn in dataTable.Columns)
{
    indexCommand += $" {dataColumn.ColumnName} TEXT";
}
db.Execute(indexCommand);
```

But this throws error - 'exceeds library limit of 31 bytes'
I spent some time googling about the documentation without any luck. Can someone help me with the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NRediSearch library should usually make this redundant. However, if you do need to do this manually: each keyword/etc is a different parameter to redis. The command is just `"FT.CREATE"`, with an array of 7 (looking casually) arguments.

Comment: Sorry just trying to understand your answer correctly. When you say NRediSearch makes this redundant, do you mean it creates index automatically and i dont need to create it manually? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @user979189 yes, there are APIs for creating an index; for example https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/src/NRediSearch/Client.cs#L316